# How to import a json file in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My file `data.json` contains a json object like:

```
{ "k": : "..some object...", "a": [ "...", "bbb" ] }
```

In Node I am able to do:

```
let data = require("./data.json");
```

and get the whole object in the json file into the variable `data`.

How do I achieve the same in the Chrome browser?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? You should be able to find a bunch of resources on how to read files (and the possible problems especially with chrome) here on SO or in the www.

Comment: I tried different ways of imitating the Node code in the browser but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are fetching the json file from the server:

```
fetch(urlOfJsonFile)
.then(function(response)
{
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data)
{
    //Use data as javascript object
})
```